# How to Airdrop between Macbook Pro and iPad Air

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad

Trying to airdrop from my Mac to my iPad however I cannot see my iPad from the Airdrop interface on the Mac.

Help..

Thanks,
Shix

Comment: OS version numbers for both devices would be helpful here. The iOS team at Apple decided to implement AirDrop completely differently than the pre-existing OS X implementation, so they weren't compatible until both iOS and OS X were updated to do AirDrop in a new, compatible way.

Comment: I have the iOS version El Capitan v10.11.11on the Mac and iOS 9.1 on the iPad. Software is up to date on both devices and AirDrop was switched on, on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure AirDrop is turned on from the iPad's control centre. Is your iPad on iOS 7 or later? It needs to be for AirDrop support.

Comment: I have the iOS version El Capitan v10.11.11on the Mac and iOS 9.1 on the iPad. Software is up to date on both devices and AirDrop was switched on, on both devices.